# VBA PowerPoint Write to Excel on Slide Change in Slideshow

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am attempting to log (1. what slide and 2. the time) to a spreadsheet each time a slide is viewed in presentation mode.  I don't want to have the spreadsheet open when I do this and I want it to save automatically.  I've been screwing around with it for a few hours now, and I've had varying success.  I can't seem to get it to work as intended.

Here's the code I've crammed together so far:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strSheet As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim curentSlide As Integer
    Dim timez As Date
    Dim z As Integer
    strSheet = "test.xlsx"
    strPath = "C:\PPToutput\"
    strSheet = strPath & strSheet
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0
    counter = counter + 1

    currentslide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    timez = Now()

    If Not IsNull(appExcel) And counter < 2 Then
        Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        appExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strSheet)
        Set wkb = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook
        Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
        wks.Activate
    End If
    appExcel.Application.Visible = True
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Slide " & currentslide
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = timez
    wks.Columns.AutoFit
    wkb.SaveAs
    Set appExcel = Nothing
    appExcel.Workbooks.Close
    appExcel.Quit
    Set appExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Be specific about which part is not working as intended. And by "don't want to have the spreadsheet open..." do you mean you don't want Excel visible or not open at all? It would be rather hard to write to a Range if Excel is not open...

Comment: Let me clarify:  I would like for Excel to be hidden from the user's view when it is being written to.  This is intended to record PowerPoint presentation times from slide to slide and from start to finish.  

Ideally the script would open Excel in the background, write a new line each time the slide changes and save and close when the PowerPoint presentation ends.  Hopefully the edited code above is easier to read. I know that code is flawed.  It opens too many instances of Excel without writing to them properly.

Comment: What version of PowerPoint are you using? Is this code running in an add-in?

Comment: Here are a few thoughts: 1) declare your Excel object variables as static, otherwise they will always be created new and thus triggering creation of a new instance of Excel, 2) use `appExcel Is Nothing` to test if it is initialized, 3) declare counter as static, 4) if the excel workbook location is in fact hard-coded, make it a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the code out, but something I noticed is that this line:

```
appExcel.Application.Visible = False
```

comes after the excel program does stuff. I would imagine the workbook opening would be visible because that happens before this line.

Also, I don't see where you're telling the OnSlideShowPageChange sub anything about the workbook you created in the SlideShowBegin sub. You're telling it to do something with a range, which is not the one you declared earlier. So, it thinks you're talking about some range in the powerpoint. Do powerpoints even have ranges?

The other mistake is that you set all of your public declarations to nothing. Once you try to call them again, you're calling nothing. It's still a good idea to do that in your error handler, but not as a normal part of the process.

Look at the [untested] changes I made and see if they make sense:

```
Public appExcel As Excel.Application
Public wkb As Excel.Workbook
Public wks As Excel.Worksheet
Public rng As Excel.Range
Public strSheet As String
Public strPath As String
Public intRowCounter As Integer
Public intColumnCounter As Integer
Public itm As Object

Sub SlideShowBegin()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

strSheet = "test.xlsx"
strPath = "C:\PPToutput\"
strSheet = strPath & strSheet
Debug.Print strSheet
'Select export folder

Dim curentSlide As Integer
Dim timez As Date
Dim z As Integer
Dim placeholder1 As String
Dim placeholder2 As String
currentslide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
timez = Now()

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appExcel.Application.Visible = False
appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strSheet)
Set wkb = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
wks.Activate
wks.Range("A1").Value = "Current Slide"
wks.Range("B1").Value = "Time"

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:      
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox strSheet & " doesn't exist", vbOKOnly, _
        "Error"
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & "; Description: ", vbOKOnly, _
        "Error"
    End If

    Set appExcel = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set msg = Nothing
    Set nms = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set itm = Nothing

End Sub

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
   Dim curentSlide As Integer
   Dim timez As Date
   Dim z As Integer
   Dim placeholder1 As String
   Dim placeholder2 As String

   currentslide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
   timez = Now()
   wks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Slide " & currentslide
   wks.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = timez
   wks.Columns.AutoFit
   wkb.Save

   If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = _
        SSW.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.EndingSlide Then
        wkb.Save
        wkb.Close
    End If
End Sub
Sub SlideShowEnd()
    wkb.Save
    wkb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You might be better off writing the slide indices and times to an array; you could then open your spreadsheet/write to it/close at the time the slide show ends instead of launching Excel repeatedly or launching it and keeping it open throughout the slideshow.

Comment: That's a really good idea. I was just pointing out errors that could cause OP's code to not work properly. You're right though. That would be a much better way to go.

Comment: I really should have commented on OP's post, not yours.  Didn't mean it to sound like I was critiquing yours.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged your code a bit so that the initialization only occurs once during the slide show. I added another procedure to close Excel once the slide show has ended.

```
Private appExcel As Excel.Application
Private wkb As Excel.Workbook
Private wks As Excel.Worksheet
Private counter As Integer

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)

    ' initialization
    Dim strSheet As String
    Dim strPath As String
    strSheet = "test.xlsx"
    strPath = "C:\PPToutput\"
    strSheet = strPath & strSheet
    Debug.Print strSheet, appExcel Is Nothing
    If appExcel Is Nothing Then
        Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        appExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        appExcel.WindowState = xlMinimized
        appExcel.Visible = True
        Set wkb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(strSheet)
        Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
        counter = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    End If

    ' make log entry
    Dim currentSlide As Integer
    currentSlide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    counter = counter + 1
    wks.Range("A" & counter).Value = "Slide " & currentSlide
    wks.Range("B" & counter).Value = Now()

End Sub

Sub OnSlideShowTerminate(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    If Not appExcel Is Nothing Then
        wks.Columns.AutoFit
        appExcel.WindowState = xlNormal
        wkb.Close True
        appExcel.Quit
    End If
    Set appExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

If it were my code, I'd also factor out the initialization code and put it in its own procedure so that the OnSlideShowPageChange procedure focused on the logging of the slide changes.